# Java - Saxon API - Write to file in "append" mode

Tags: java, xquery, saxon

I am using Saxon 8 to parse XQuery and analyse the xml file return by the API.
The problem is that the FileWriter passed in argument is always used in "overwrite" mode even if the constructor is using true parameter.

Example of what I have :

```
sqc.compileQuery(new FileReader(xq.getCurrentXQueryFile())).run(dqc, new StreamResult(new FileWriter(xq.getResultsFile(), true)), props);
```

sqc is a StaticQueryContext.
the "true" is optional parameter for FileWriter constructor to use append mode.

So as I said it still rewrite the file on each "compileQuery".
I tried to check the source but it's really too heavy for my level...

So if someone knows if there is a "clean" way to get multiple results in a single file, thanks ! :-)

PS : I know it could be easy to create one file per launch then get the content of all files in a single one but it's not what I call "clean".

Comment: `new FileOutputStream(xq.getResultsFile(), true)` would be better for the charset encoding. About the error: try out replacing `xq.getResulsFile()` with some static file to see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact it is Saxon 9 HE not 8 and I found the issue.
In append mode the tag "

```
props.setProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
```

Now I have other issue but not realated to api, my xml is not valide against the sax parser (no root node...as I append the root node from xquery 2 times the parser want a real root node but I will managed that. ;-)).

Thanks again.

Comment: Consider using the technique described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25886430/how-to-append-to-certain-line-of-file/25888759#25888759 to avoid the problem with the root/document element.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a very ancient version of Saxon (not sure which: "Saxon 8" could be anything from 8.0 to 8.9 which is a sequence of releases shipped between about 2001 and 2007; the current version is 9.8). You're also using a very old API which is still supported to a degree but changed quite a bit over successive releases, which means it's hard to give you precise advice. I would strongly suggest that you move forward to Saxon 9.8 and use the s9api API which was designed for stability and has proved very stable in practice.

Having said that, it's hard to see exactly what's going wrong here. Saxon is simply going to write characters to the Writer that you provide; there's no way it can do anything else. And the Writer that you are providing is one that, according to the Java specs, appends data to a file. One possibility is that the writer isn't being properly closed after writing, but there's no way we could investigate that possibility on such an old release.

So I think you should try and provide a complete repro in a simple and complete standalone program using an up-to-date version of Saxon; that we we can help you find the bug.