# appending to existing XML in java

Tags: java, xml, dom, sax

In my code, I need to check if a file(xml) exist or not. if exists i need to read it(parse it) and append to it, order doesn't matter so i can append anywhere. if doesn't exist I have to create it and then append.

here is the code I wrote:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumnetBuilder();
Document doc;

if(!file.exists()) {
  doc = builder.newDocument();
  doc.appendChild(doc.createElement("a"));
 } else {
   doc = builder.parse(new File("path"));
 }
  //adding more elements
```

this code works. BUT, this file can get huge and I don't want to parse the entire file everytime. I don't need to parse it I just want to append a new node to it so is there a better way of doing this? 
I tried XMLstreamWriter and SAX but i'm not sure how to add to existing file with SAX after parsing partially, since SAX is for reading not writing. so if this is the correct answer would someone please give me an example?

thank you

Comment: You could just open a `RandomAccessFile`, read backwards to find the start of your closing tag, then write out your new fragment.

Comment: Consider the technique described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25886430/how-to-append-to-certain-line-of-file/25888759#25888759